# how to check default column value in sqlite3 is set to infinite in "c" / native sqlite3

Tags: c, sqlite

I have attempted to establish a graph using sqlite3 as follows, and just wanted to know how I may check that the "infinite" value in the graph is treated as infinite by sqlite3.

```
sqlite> create table graph(nodeA INT, nodeB INT, length INT DEFAULT inf);

sqlite> insert into graph values(1,2,0);
sqlite> insert into graph values(1,3,null);
sqlite> insert into graph values (2,3,"inf");

sqlite> select * from graph;
1|2|0
1|3|
2|3|inf
```

Any good suggestions?

Comment: How about inserting lots of items in random order, and then running `select * from graph order by length asc`?

Comment: Though creative suggestions are interesting it doesn't really provide a definitive answer. Technically I have defined length as INT, so "inf" should(!) be infinite, but what when I export the value to f.x. python. Is that then still the same interpretation of infinite?

Comment: I misunderstood your question then: I though you weren't looking for interpretations outside `sqlite`. There is no `int` number in `C` reserved to represent infinity.